# How to style textbox or drop down list box after these are dynamically created and populated?

Tags: javascript, html, css

After dynamically created text box or drop list box these are populated dynamically. Can anyone help to style with css these dynamically created drop down list or text box etc.

Here is my code I want to style

tag containing "Select size" and "select color"

```
$secondScreen .= <<<MARKUP

<div class="{$giftcss}">
   <input type="hidden" name= "product_id{$i}" value="{$productId}"/> 
   <div class="gift-img"><img src="http://{$domainName}/gifts/images/{$prod_img_name}" height="250"></div>
   <div class="divider"></div>
   <div class="gift-desc"><h3>{$product_name}</h3><span>{$product_desc}</span></div>
   <div style="width:100%;">
     <h3 style="display:{$headlineVisib}">Customize your gift</h3><br>
     <p  style="display:{$sizeVisibility};">Select Size<select id = "prod_size{$i}" name="prod_size{$i}" >{$sizeOptionValues}</select></p>
     <p style="display:{$colorVisibility};">Select Color<select id = "prod_color{$i}" name="prod_color{$i}" >{$colorOptionValues}</select></p>
     <p style="display:{$personalisedVisib};">{$personalisedMsg}</p>
   </div>
MARKUP;
```

Comment: Got any code or a JSFiddle?

Comment: Whatever you are creating dynamically, attach a `class` to them while you're making them and style using those classes in css.

Comment: If you already have your stylesheet, just add the classes to your HTML elements.

Comment: Please show me some examples or share any link if any

Answer (score 1):

The solution is using JavaScript style attribute 
Example:

```
var element = document.getElementById("element");
element.style.color = "#F90";
element.style.backgroundColor = "#F0F0F0";
```

Or you can write your css as usual

```
element.cssText = "color:#F90; background-color:#F0F0F0";
```

Comment: Second one is a better option 9/10 times